# Compiling under VC++ boost+icu statically

Tags: c++, windows, boost, icu

I want to compile the following code with `VC++ 2010` and `boost` with `icu` Unicode support and link it as `static`, it compiles without error but still it asks for `icuuc52.dll, icudt52.dll, icuin52.dll`, what did I do wrong? ICU was compiled `static`, boost with icu compiled `static` and I link as `static` under VC++ with the ICU option `/D "U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex/icu.hpp>

#pragma comment (lib, "icuuc.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "icuin.lib")

int main()
{
   static const std::string pattern("^.*" "\303\226" ".*$");
   static const std::string   test1("SCH" "\303\226" "NE");
   static const std::string   test2("sch" "\303\266" "ne");
   static const boost::u32regex exp=boost::make_u32regex(pattern, boost::regex::icase);
   const char *result = (boost::u32regex_match(test1, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
   std::cout << "Testing \"" << test1 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern
      << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
   result = (boost::u32regex_match(test2, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
   std::cout << "Testing \"" << test2 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern
      << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
}
```

[image]

full command line used:

> cl.exe /O2 /MT /EHsc /D "U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION" /I
>   C:\local\boost_1_55_0 /I C:\icu\include uniregboost.cpp /link
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE Kernel32.Lib User32.lib advapi32.lib
>   /libpath:"C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib" /libpath:"C:\icu\lib"

Comment: this isn't an answer, but just a debugging idea- can you check all of the .lib files involved and make sure they are 'big' (i.e. not stub references to DLLs)?   ICU, and the data building tools, don't build statically for VC2010 by default (nor, I suspect, easily)

Comment: Yes, `libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s-1_55.lib` about 10Mb, `icuuc.lib` 788 Kb, `icuin.lib` 1,2 Mb

Comment: yes, but there's some other .lib on your disk that refers to icuuc52.dll or you wouldn't see that error message. What about the data, icudt.lib?

Comment: `icudt.lib` about 2Kb, maybe here the problem? I see it imports the dll

Comment: Any help from anyone?

Comment: How are you building ICU? As far as I know, if you use the provided Visual Studio Solution/Projects, your options are to link against the stub data (the small icudt.lib) or the DLL version of the data.

If you want to use fully static data, you'll need to either patch the Solution/Projects or use the Cygwin based build.